# Ctrl + B not working with vertex

Tags: bevel

I'm new to Blender and I ran into this problem, when I press the combination of keys "Ctrl + B", instead of the appearance of corner smoothing points, nothing happens. I cannot understand why, and when I smooth the corners in a cube, everything works great.Screenshot of the bevel setting is attached below.Thanks in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Blender makes a distinction between <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>B</kbd>, *Bevel Edges*, and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>B</kbd>, *Bevel Vertices*.

So, use the other shortcut, or, having reached the Adjust Last Operation panel visible in your illustration, switch at the top from 'Edges' to 'Vertices'.

(In other panels, or the *Bevel* modifier, it might be a small checkbox - 'Only Vertices')

I didn't realize.. as @moonboots has pointed out - there is a hitch in some Blender 2.90.x's meaning the shortcut doesn't work: you have to go to the panel, and switch it there.

Comment: 2.90.1 is buggy though, shift ctrl B doesn't work, you need to go in the Operator box and choose Vertices, it has been corrected in 2.91

Comment: @moonboots Ahhh! Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Alternatively, you can bevel a vertex with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>B</kbd> and then <kbd>V</kbd>.